# What is meant by a single-threaded, event-driven I/O system?

Tags: node.js

I am trying to understand how the node.js works, and in the features of node.js, I read the following statement:

> Node.js is a single-threaded but highly scalable system that utilizes
>   JavaScript as its scripting language. It uses asynchronous,
>   event-driven I/O instead of separate processes or threads. It is able
>   to achieve high output via single-threaded event loop and non-blocking
>   I/O.

What does being a single-threaded system mean?

Comment: You don't seem to have put enough effort on internet searching for multi-threading paradigm, program execution, how node.js is different, what is event based execution and many other topics. If you do, you'd have a more concise question to ask. Please don't use SO unless you have already researched enough.

Comment: @binariedMe Thanks for your helpful suggestion, I will put more research into it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Thread***

> In computer science, a thread of execution is the smallest sequence of programmed instructions that can be managed independently by a scheduler, which is typically a part of the operating system.
>
> - [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing))

That means that a thread is a simple flow of instruction. An application can be single threaded (so imagine it as a single line going from the entry point of the application to its end) or multi-threaded (imagine a tree: the whole app starts from 1 point, than it branches out more and more).

> **Single threaded processes** contain the execution of instructions in a single sequence. In other words, one command is processes at a time.
>
> The opposite of single threaded processes are **multithreaded processes**. These processes allow the execution of multiple parts of a program at the same time. These are lightweight processes available within the process.
>
> - [*Single-threaded and Multi-threaded Processes*](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/single-threaded-and-multi-threaded-processes)  by David Meador

Comment: Thanks, this is of much help. I have always come across terms such as single-threaded and multithreaded - yet never had the actual coding experience for a multithreaded processes to see the difference in practicality. I suppose the latter uses concepts like locks, mutexes and semaphores

Comment: Please be sure to include explicit citations and use quote formatting when quoting content from other sources.